# Cursor NotSerializableException in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization, cursor

I need to pass a Cursor object from one android emulator to another. But when I try to serialize it, I am getting a "NotSerialiableException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor" error.

I know that one way to handle this is to tear down to serializable classes & serialize (on one emulator), de-serialize & rebuild the Cursor object (on another emulator).

Is there no other way to do this? I was looking at Parcelable and I am not so sure if this is what I want. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a chance in hell that that'll work. A cursor is basically a view of the contents of your database.

What are you trying to do exactly? How are you trying to pass the data between emulators? You're probably going to want to put the data from the cursor into something that IS serializable, like a map.

Comment: I need to implement a distributed hash table. So the key-value pairs I need to store are distributed amongst several android devices. And I should be able to query a device for a particular key. 

SO I was planning on passing the Cursor from device 2 to device 1. But Cursor is NOT Serializable (and neither is CrossProcessCursorWrapper). Data is passed over TCP sockets. So I am stuck.

Comment: I guess the only way then is to have a List/Map of key-value pairs, and pass that object instead of trying to pass a Cursor.

Comment: I was under the impression that a Cursor is an object in memory which reads from the DB and hence, is now detached from the actual DB contents itself. That is why I thought I could pass around a Cursor object. But I might be wrong.